# Wrong TFM generated by mf2pt1 in TeXLive 2013

Tags: fonts, texlive, metapost

I need to generate a font from METAFONT file.
I used *mf2pt1* and generated PFB file and TFM file, but TFM file was incorrect.

I tried to generate TMF file of *cmr10.mf* by mf2pt1, then looked at *cmr10.tmf* by *tftopl*.

```
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 16761661120)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.020833)
   (STRETCH R 0.010417)
   (SHRINK R 0.006945)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.02691)
   (QUAD R 0.0625)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.006945)
   )
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 40)
   (KRN C l R -0.017362)
   (KRN C L R -0.019965)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.004861)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.004861)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.004861)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.004861)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.004861)
   (STOP)
```

But looked at *cmr10.tfm* distributed by TeXLive 2013,

```
(FAMILY CMR)
(FACE O 352)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX TEXT)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 11374260171)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.333334)
   (STRETCH R 0.166667)
   (SHRINK R 0.111112)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111112)
   )
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 40)
   (KRN C l R -0.277779)
   (KRN C L R -0.319446)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.077779)
   (STOP)
```

Like this, kerning information are different in two files.

In addition, I tried to generate TFM file mf2pt1 in **TeXLive 2012**
and looked at this.

```
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 11374260171)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.333334)
   (STRETCH R 0.166667)
   (SHRINK R 0.111112)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111112)
   )
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 40)
   (KRN C l R -0.277779)
   (KRN C L R -0.319446)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.077779)
   (STOP)
```

This TFM file is nearly equal what is distributed by TeXLive 2013.

mf2pt1 uses MetaPost(mpost) to generate TFM file, and MetaPost updated version 1.803 from version 1.504 in TeXLive 2013.
So I think this problem is occurred by something bug of MetaPost 1.803.

Thanks.

**P.S.(7/6)**

I read Perl source code of `mf2pt1.pl` and checked a command which execute `mpost` to make TFM file.
At lines 429-430 in `mf2pt1.pl`,

```
execute_command 1, ("mpost", "-mem=mf2pt1", "-progname=mpost",
                    "\\mode:=localfont; mag:=$mag; bpppix $bpppix; nonstopmode; input $mffile");
```

And generate following command (in this case to use *cmr10.mf*)

```
$ mpost -mem=mf2pt1 -progname=mpost '\mode:=localfont; mag:=100.375; bpppix 0.02; nonstopmode; input cmr10.mf'
```

I run this command with both `mpost 1.803` and `mpost 1.504`, generated each TFM files, and compered these files.
Then the kerning information of TMF file generated by `mpost 1.803` was incorrect.

So I think why this problem occurred are some of

- bugs of MetaPost (`mpost`) 1.803
- errors of `mf2pt1.mp` (called by `mf2pt1`)

I would like to solve this problem, but I don't have knowledge enough to solve this...

**P.S.(7/8)**

I read `mf2pt1.mp`, then understood that `mfplain.mp` is called by `mf2pt1.mp`.
According to [MetaPost manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/base/manual/mpman.pdf),

> Even though MetaPost has the primitives for generating fonts,
>   many of the font-making primitives and internal variables
>   that are part of Plain METAFONT are not defined in Plain MetaPost.
>   Instead, there is a separate macro package called mfplain
>   that defines the macros required to allow MetaPost to process Knuth’s Computer Modern fonts

So I compered `mfpain.mf` in **TeXLive 2012** with that in **TeXLive 2013**.
But they are equal.

Therefore, I think the cause of generating wrong TFM files is **MetaPost primitives** for generating TFM files.
I read [change log](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/CHANGES?view=markup&revision=1919&root=metapost) of MetaPost,
But I can't seem to change the primitives for generating TFM files.

Comment: I can confirm the output; the error might also depend on `mf2pt1`; possibly a bad interaction with the new version of `mpost`.

Comment: Any news about the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried

```
mf2pt1 cmr10
```

with today's (2014-05-3) update available in the development version of TeX Live 2014. Doing `tftopl cmr10` reveals the following file:

```
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 11374260171)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.333334)
   (STRETCH R 0.166667)
   (SHRINK R 0.111112)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111112)
   )
```

and doing `diff` with the output of `tftopl` from the standard `cmr10.tfm` file shows that the newly generated one misses

```
(FAMILY CMR)
(FACE O 352)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX TEXT)
```

and for some characters the height is computed inaccurately: for characters

```
O 44   $
O 45   %
O 50   (
O 51   )
O 52   *
O 57   /
O 133  [
O 135  ]
```

the height is 0.75 in the original metrics, while it's not specified in the metric file produced by `mf2pt1`.

The log file has many warnings `Replacing filldraw with fill.`. There are also several internal errors in the run of `fontforge`, such as

```
Internal Error (overlap) in A: couldn't find a needed exit from an intersection
Internal Error (overlap) in A: couldn't find a needed exit from an intersection
Internal Error (overlap) in G: monotonic is both needed and unneeded (451,274)->(621,271). x=587.505 (prev=585.5)
```

However, the main issue seems to have been solved.

Comment: Thank you.

In [MetaPost ChangeLog](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/CHANGES?view=markup&root=metapost)

> * Fixed TFM generation issues (various scale-related errors).

at Version 1.890.
So I think this issue was solved by this fix.